# Integration tests with mongodb

Tags: mongodb, phpunit, bdd, behat

I'm using mongodb as my main database, so on my integration tests I try to test if my system handles the data as expected. The process is as follow:

1. Insert data on needed collections to prepare scenario
2. Perform call to the system
3. Validate data change or exist on database, depending of the scenario

I'm using behat as my BDD testing tool and I implement on my FeatureContext to insert and read data from collections, something like this:

Given I have the following data on collection Brand

```
[
    {
        "_id": "575df0b00419c905492d0461",
        "name": "Adidas",
        "image": "adidas.png"
    }
]
```

Then I validate the following data exists on collection Brand

```
[
    {
        "_id": "575df0b00419c905492d0461",
        "name": "Adidas",
        "image": "adidas.png"
    }
]
```

## EDIT

```
/**
 * @Given I have the following data on collection :collectionName
 * @param string $collectionName
 * @param PyStringNode $collectionData
 * @throws Exception
 */
public function iHaveTheFollowingDataOnCollection($collectionName, PyStringNode $collectionData)
{
    $data = json_decode($collectionData->getRaw(), true);

    foreach ($data as $index => $element) {
        foreach ($element as $key => $value) {
            if ($key === '_id') {
                $data[$index][$key] = new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($value);
            }

            if (strpos($key, "@") !== false) {
                $key = explode("@", $key)[1];
                $data[$index][$key] = array(
                    "\$ref" => $value["\$ref"],
                    "\$id" => new \MongoDB\BSON\ObjectID($value["\$id"]),
                    "\$db" => $value["\$db"],
                );
            }

            if ($value === "UNIX_TIME()") {
                $data[$index][$key] = time();
            }
        }
    }

    $collection = $this->db->$collectionName;

    foreach ($data as $document) {
        $collection->insertOne($document);
    }
}
```

## END EDIT

The issue is that I have at least 1k different scenarios on different features and with that heavy usage test randomly fails becase it don't find  expected data on collection.

My first thought is that exist some delay on insertion and availability of the data.

Any thoughts and how to fix it?

Comment: dumb idea, but you could create another collection in the same db just for keeping some state around that tells you when the data is available. poll periodically (or do callbacks) in your test suite until data is ready.

Comment: thanks for the idea @matiaselgart but i dont get how to update that status since the data change on each scenarios en even several times on each scenarios depending on the test case so updating another collection will have the same effect

Comment: Could you share some example code of your feature/context here?

Comment: @PeterChung i add the function that handles the insertion on mongodb collection

Comment: @bitgandtter Could you provide a complete example which can be used for reproducing the issue? including feature, context, behat.yml...

Comment: sadly @PeterChung i cant, its a private project for my company and i cant publish code, but the issue its replicable under heavy test execution, example 200 behat scenarios all of them using mongodb as explained on the post